# Why do I get C2883: function declaration conflicts with - introduced by using-delcaration when overriding only one overload from a base class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does the following code give me a compiler error?

```
struct lol {
    void foo(int hi) { }
    void foo(lol x) { }
};

void funcit() {
    struct duh : public lol {
        using lol::foo;

        void foo(lol x) { }
    };

    lol().foo(10);
    lol().foo(lol());
    duh().foo(10);
    duh().foo(lol());
}

int main() {
    funcit();
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect it to compile, wherein `duh::foo` would call `lol::foo` - only overriding one of the overloads. Using Visual Studio Express 2012, I get this error:

```
error C2883: 'funcit::duh::foo' : function declaration conflicts with 'lol::foo' introduced by using-declaration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct and compiles with GCC 4.8.1. This appears to be a bug in MSVC 2012. Lifting the struct out of the function will cause it to work properly:

```
struct lol {
    void foo(int hi) { }
    void foo(lol x) { }
};

namespace { 
    struct duh : public lol {
        using lol::foo;

        void foo(lol x) { }
    };
}

void funcit() {
    lol().foo(10);
    lol().foo(lol());
    duh().foo(10);
    duh().foo(lol());
}

int main() {
    funcit();
    return 0;
}
```